# Sync a local directory with a remote via SFTP from the commandline

Tags: command-line, sftp, file-transfer

I have a local directory `./sync` from which i wish to sync any changes to a remote directory, let's say `~/folder` on `ssh://remote` (as defined in ssh config).

I can do this with WinSCP (Windows only), but is there also a simple way to do the same on the commandline? Preferably without a script or cronjob.

My search brought up `rsync` and `unison` but I could not get either to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer to the question above but it may still solve your problem.

Jetbrains IDEs and Visual Studio Code have respective features / plugins for syncing files to a remote:
[Jetbrains Deploy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLzgxUfYdpg)

[VSCode Plugin](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/03/remote-ssh-tips-and-tricks)